# Using Learning To Rank on textual documents?

Tags: python-3.x, ranking, information-retrieval, supervised-learning

i need some help in implementing Learning To Rank (LTR). It is related to my semester project and I'm totally new to this. The details are as follows:
I gathered around 90 documents  and populated 10 user queries. Now i have to rank these documents based on each query using three algorithms specifically LambdaMart, AdaRank, and Coordinate Ascent. Previously i applied clustering techniques on Vector Space Model but that was easy. However in this case, I don't know how to change the data according to these algorithms. As i have this textual data( document and queries) in txt format in separate files. I have searched for solutions online and I'm unable to find a proper solution so can anyone here please guide me in the right direction i.e. Steps. I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have applied the clustering in vector space model. the input of these algorithms are also vectors. 
Why don't you have a look at the standard data set introduced for learning to rank issue ([Letor benchmark](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/letor-benchmark-collection-research-learning-rank-information-retrieval/)) in which documents are shown in vectors of features?
There is also implementation of these algorithm provided in java (RankLib), which may give you the idea to solve the problem. I hope, this help you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I studied that paper you referred and looked into the dataset. However, there is nothing about how they constructed that actual dataset. The dataset consists only numeric values and query references in that. In my case i have documents and a VSM (word by document matrix). I'm still struggling to turn that into something like Ohsumsd dataset.